# Issue with comparision of day in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am working on PL/SQL. Meanwhile, I required to compare whether the date in table is friday or not. I applied the below code but it's still executing the 'else' part of program. Can anyone please tell me the way?

```
begin
    select dt into dat from ticket_booking where id=1;
    dy := to_char(dat, 'DAY');
    if  dy = to_char('FRIDAY') then
        dbms_output.put_line(dy);
    else
        dbms_output.put_line('didnt print'||dy);
    end if;
end;
```

Comment: `dy = to_char('FRIDAY')`? Why are you using to_char on something that's already a string?! Instead, you should be checking for `if dy = 'FRIDAY'`. And, even better, you should use the optional third parameter when checking the date to make sure it outputs in English, if that's what you're after - i.e. `dy := to_char(dat, 'fmDAY', 'nls_date_language=english');` That would make sure your code (which is assuming the date returns in English) will always receive the date in English, regardless of what the underlying NLS parameters are set to.

Comment: thanks for reply. I got it. Can you tell me significance of 'fm' Day in code

Comment: It's funny what [the documentation contains](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00216)...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `DAY`, you need to use `fmDAY`.

```
begin
select dt into dat from ticket_booking where id=1;
dy := to_char(dat, 'fmDAY');
if  dy = to_char('FRIDAY') then
    dbms_output.put_line(dy);
else
    dbms_output.put_line('didnt print'||dy);
end if;
end;
```

Comment: thanks for answer. but one thing i wanna ask what does 'fm' means here?

Comment: As I cannot explain better than what is present in Oracle Docs here is the [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00216)

Comment: The FM and FX modifiers, used in format models in the TO_CHAR function, control blank padding and exact format checking.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace 'DAY' with 'Fmday' and boom the code runs :).

```
DECLARE
  dat DATE;
  dy  VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  SELECT dt INTO dat FROM ticket_booking WHERE id=1;
  dy   := TO_CHAR(dat, 'fmDAY');
  IF dy = TO_CHAR('FRIDAY') THEN
    dbms_output.put_line(dy);
  ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line('didnt print'||dy);
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 2):

As all above, I can add, if you don't want to use string compare use can do this
comparison

```
to_char(dat, 'DAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=''numeric date language''')
```

it's like language but in numbers, where day of weeks numerated from 1 to 7, and you can compare result in numeric values.

Comment: Thanks - I hadn't heard of this. Seems to be semi-documented as it only appears in Oracle Fusion Middleware documentation which merely mentions it in passing.

Comment: Yes, you are right it is a undocumented. I found out it on one oracle forum a time ago , if I remember right it comes from version 10g.